# Turn off Google Maps POI programatically on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API with a stylized map, and on my website there is an option to show or hide Points of Interests. By default, the POIs are on. When the user clicks the "hide" button, I want the map to turn off the POIs but keep the rest of the theme style settings.

I know of the Map.setOptions function, however when I use it this way:

```
map.setOptions({styles: [
  {
   "featureType": "poi",
   "stylers": [
    { "visibility": "off" }
  ]
}
]});
```

It overrides all of the existing theme's settings, reverting to the default google maps look but with POIs turned off. Is there a way to just turn off POIs and keep the current theme?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: You probably need to keep the options you are using around, modify the poi value and set the entire options again.

Comment: Have you seen [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/hiding-features)?  (how to hide the POIs from a custom style)

Comment: @geocodezip Yes that's what I thought too, I was hoping there would be a simpler and cleaner way.

Comment: @geocodezip I have, but that one uses the .setOptions function too, which sets the whole style to whatever the argument is instead of modifying just that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is a MVC Object, it has setters and getters for all its "options".

This works for me (but it involves knowing that the entry to hide the POIs is first in the array):

```
// Apply new JSON when the user chooses to hide/show features.
document.getElementById('hide-poi').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var styles = map.get("styles");
  styles.splice(0, 0, {
    featureType: 'poi',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'off'
    }]
  });
  map.set("styles", styles);
});
document.getElementById('show-poi').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var styles = map.get("styles");
  styles = styles.slice(1);
  map.set("styles", styles);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ovegzy6n/3/)

hidden:
[image: hidden POIs]
shown:
[image: shown POIs]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.86,
      lng: 151.209
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    styles: nightMode
  });

  // Add controls to the map, allowing users to hide/show features.
  var styleControl = document.getElementById('style-selector-control');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(styleControl);

  // Apply new JSON when the user chooses to hide/show features.
  document.getElementById('hide-poi').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var styles = map.get("styles");
    styles.splice(0, 0, {
      featureType: 'poi',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off'
      }]
    });
    map.set("styles", styles);
  });
  document.getElementById('show-poi').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var styles = map.get("styles");
    styles = styles.slice(1);
    map.set("styles", styles);
  });
}
var map;
var nightMode = [{
    featureType: 'poi',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#d59563'
    }]
  },
  {
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#242f3e'
    }]
  },
  {
    elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#242f3e'
    }]
  },
  {
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#746855'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'administrative.locality',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#d59563'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'poi.park',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#263c3f'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'poi.park',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#6b9a76'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#38414e'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#212a37'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#9ca5b3'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'road.highway',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#746855'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'road.highway',
    elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#1f2835'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'road.highway',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#f3d19c'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'transit',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#2f3948'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'transit.station',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#d59563'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#17263c'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#515c6d'
    }]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#17263c'
    }]
  }
];
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.map-control {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  margin: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  /* Hide the control initially, to prevent it from appearing
     before the map loads. */
  display: none;
}


/* Display the control once it is inside the map. */

#map .map-control {
  display: block;
}

.selector-control {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div id="style-selector-control" class="map-control">
  <input type="radio" name="show-hide" id="hide-poi" class="selector-control">
  <label for="hide-poi">Hide</label>
  <input type="radio" name="show-hide" id="show-poi" class="selector-control" checked="checked">
  <label for="show-poi">Show</label>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```